# Description shows on one page but not on the other. Same product

Tags: magento, field-description

For some reason once I added the description to the product it shows up if you locate the product via catalog. But not when you get to the page via search.

Catalog (description present): http://www.dentalhealthessentials.com/teeth-whitening/polanight/polanight-10.html

Search page (description is missing): http://www.dentalhealthessentials.com/polanight-10.html

This is the same product in Admin. I've tried flushing Cache, refreshing it everything and still the same result. The page without description is showing how it looked before i added the description.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: i think you have used two templates for the product view page or you have get the category description instead of product description

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is still not solved, try flushing your browser cache as well because the description appears on the two links you provided.

Comment: I turned off Full Page Cashing and the problem went away. As soon as I activate it back... description does not show.

Comment: EE 1.14.1.0 no modules